# If change the url key of Migrated products it doesn't work,still old url is calling,on category page url key is working but strange

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration

I have migrated from Magento 1 to Magento 2 and when updating/changing the URL key of a migrated products "Test" from "test" to "test2" still getting old URL of this product on the frontend **"mydomainname/test.html"** while it should be **"mydomainname/test2.html"**.

but When I deleted old URL key and added new URL key from **"URL Rewrite"** module then I'm able to access product directly by new URL(mydomainname/test2.html).

Suppose this product **"Test"** is assigned in the category **"XYZ"**. when I visited on XYZ category page to visit on "Test" product then instead of getting **"Domainname/XYZ/test2.html"** URL getting a strange URL 
 for the "Test" product only. 
while other migrated products URL in this category is very user-friendly ("Domainname/XYZ/urlkey.html").

**Note:-** I've already gone through the R&D and didn't get any useful solution.
Already performed reindexing, cache clean etc.

Comment: use this extension: https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites

Comment: thanks for the reply! we've more than 4k products, after changing the url each time should we run this extension?

Comment: you need to run it once only than all will work in further update.

Comment: I tried the extension but it took too much time to create url_key. after running the Ext 4-5 HR i left the system for an entire night with running the Ext but in the morning i don't know how my console was closed and frontend categories stopped working getting 404 page.

Finally i resolved the issue by updating url-key via import.

Answer (score 0):

As I R&D and found that **this is a migration issue**:-

**Solution 1:-** I've fixed the migration issue, to fix the issue you need to override the method **"getUrlPath()"** of the class **"\Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlPathGenerator"**:-

**Here is the override class code :-**

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\MigrationUrlKeyIssue\Model\Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite;


class ProductUrlPathGenerator extends \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlPathGenerator
{
     public function getUrlPath($product, $category = null)
    {
        // $path = $product->getData('url_path');
        $path=null ;
        if ($path === null) {
            $path = $product->getUrlKey()
                ? $this->prepareProductUrlKey($product)
                : $this->prepareProductDefaultUrlKey($product);
        }
        return $category === null
            ? $path
            : $this->categoryUrlPathGenerator->getUrlPath($category) . '/' . $path;
    }

}
```

**Solution 2:-** I tried to update the `url_key` by-product import and its work for me but this is not a perfect solution as you can't always export and import products so, always prefer solution 1.

Hope it'll help you guys!!!